# Is there a way to concat non-Redux actions in RxJS / Redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

After a successful login, I am trying to store a token in local storage before fetching a user's config. At the moment I'm just storing the token from within `mergeMap` before fetching the config in the return statement. However, I'm pretty sure there's a way to use `concat` or `concatMap` to call the store and fetch functions in sequence.

```
const authEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('auth/AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS'),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const { jwt } = action.payload;

      localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);

      return of({
        type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'
      });
    })
  );
```

Below is one of my attempts which proved unsuccessful. Although there might be other ways of handling the storing and fetching in this case from within a component, I would like to know how this pattern should work for other cases I have.

```
const authEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('auth/AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS'),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const { jwt } = action.payload;

      return concat(
        localStorage.setItem('token', jwt),
        of({ type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'})
      );
    })
  );
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your first approach though

Comment: @FanCheung Thanks. Yes, in this case it will work fine but do you know how to use concat in a case like this? In other cases I have multiple functions I need to call before the final action so creating a sequence would be ideal.

Comment: that really depends on whether those functions are sync or async ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the first approach you have stated in your question, as `localStorage.setItem()` is synchronous, thus it will always be called, before `FETCH_CONFIG` action is returned..

However, if you are looking for alternative approaches, I would suggest you to separate the logic by using the `tap()` operator before returning the `FETCH_CONFIG` action. This will also ensure that both actions are called in sequence.

```
const authEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('auth/AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS'),
    tap(({ payload: { jwt } }) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
    }),
    mergeMap((action) => (of({
      type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'
    }))
  );
```

However, if you really want to use `concat()`, you will need to wrap the `localStorage.setItem()` action in `of()` to convert it into an observable, as `concat()` requires all members to be observables, and it will need to wait for the first subscription(`localStorage.setItem()`) to be completed before the second one(`FETCH_CONFIG`) can start.

```
const authEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('auth/AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS'),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const { jwt } = action.payload;

      return concat(
        of(localStorage.setItem('token', jwt)),
        of({ type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'})
      );
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Nice to know `tap` can used like this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try use `last()` operator, Concat will emit when each item in the sequence completes itself so that's why it doesn't work.

```
  reuturn concat(
    of(localStorage.setItem('token', jwt)),
    of({ type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'})
  ).pipe(last());
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` is used for executing observables in order as previous complete.

Check doc from [learnrx.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)

> You can think of concat like a line at an ATM, the next transaction (subscription) cannot start until the previous completes!

In your example, I don't think you need any of those operators since you're not doing anything asynchronous in your flow.

You could simply change your code with the following:

```
action$.pipe(
  ofType('auth/AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS'),
  tap(action => localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload)),
  mapTo({ type: 'user/FETCH_CONFIG'})
);
```